# How to read and print first head of a file in R?

Tags: r, unix, cat, unix-head

I want to print a head of a file in R. I know how to use read.table and other input methods supported by R. I just want to know R alternatives to unix command cat or head that reads in a file and print some of them.

Thank you,

SangChul

Comment: `head()`, `tail()`, and look at `?[` for more sophisticated indexing / extracting options.

Comment: You apparently don't know yet about `readLines()` and the `n` argument of this function...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read.table()` takes an `nrows` argument for just this purpose:

```
read.table(header=TRUE, text="
    a b
    1 2
    3 4
    ", nrows=1)
#   a b
# 1 1 2
```

If you are instead reading in (possibly less structured) files with `readLines()`, you can use its `n` argument instead:

```
readLines(textConnection("a b
1 2 3 4 some other things
last"), n=1)
# [1] "a b"
```